# Uri Matcher doesn't match uri

Tags: android, uri, android-contentprovider, matcher

Here is my Uri Matcher

```
static UriMatcher buildUriMatcher() {
    UriMatcher mUriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);

    // Bind uriMatcher int constants and uris
    mUriMatcher.addURI(OneSpaceContract.CONTENT_AUTHORITY, OneSpaceContract.PATH_DRIVE, DRIVE_LIST);
    mUriMatcher.addURI(OneSpaceContract.CONTENT_AUTHORITY, OneSpaceContract.PATH_DRIVE + "/#", DRIVE_ID);
    mUriMatcher.addURI(OneSpaceContract.CONTENT_AUTHORITY, OneSpaceContract.PATH_FILE, FILE_LIST);
    mUriMatcher.addURI(OneSpaceContract.CONTENT_AUTHORITY, OneSpaceContract.PATH_FILE + "/*", FILE_ID);
    mUriMatcher.addURI(OneSpaceContract.CONTENT_AUTHORITY, OneSpaceContract.PATH_FILE + "/drive/#", FILE_LIST_WITH_DRIVE_ID);
    mUriMatcher.addURI(OneSpaceContract.CONTENT_AUTHORITY, OneSpaceContract.PATH_FILE + "/file/*", FILE_LIST_WITH_FOLDER_ID);
    mUriMatcher.addURI(OneSpaceContract.CONTENT_AUTHORITY, OneSpaceContract.PATH_FILE + "/drive/#/*", FILE_LIST_WITH_DRIVE_ID_AND_FOLDER_ID);

    // Return the new matcher!
    return mUriMatcher;
}
```

Here is PATH_FILE constant

```
 public static final String PATH_FILE = "file";
```

UriMatcher doesn't match my uri

Uri : `content://olexiimuraviov.ua.onespace_diplomaproject/file/drive/11/root`

Here is an Exception

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: 
    Unknown uri: content://olexiimuraviov.ua.onespace_diplomaproject/file/drive/11/root
    at OneSpaceProvider.query(...)
```

I tried to debug and found nothing. Uri pattern looks fine and given uri is fine too, but matcher doesn't match it. Can you help me with this issue? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Perhaps it cannot handle two wildcard segments (`#/*`).

Comment: I bet on  `mUriMatcher.addURI(OneSpaceContract.CONTENT_AUTHORITY, OneSpaceContract.PATH_FILE + "/*", FILE_ID);` [UriMatcher with replaced android.net.Uri with java.net.URI](http://ideone.com/jLvXyo)

Comment: but if you move this line at the end of the `buildUriMatcher` method... [It should work](http://ideone.com/ACyIvY)

Comment: That's work, than you! @Selvin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Selvin stated on his example, the problematic rule is the one that binds FILE_ID. The first part of the segment matches, so it won't try to find any other rule that matches at that segment. Move that rule at the end and it should be fine.